# SEO Tips and Tricks for web developers

Tags: web-development, books, seo, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I know most of the Users of Stackoverflow would have knowledge about **Search Engine Optimization(SEO)**.. Any tips and tricks about SEO for your fellow web developers ...

**EDIT:**

- Good book about SEO?
- Good blogs/websites about SEO?

Answer (score 8):

Read. Read *lots*. SEO is a science, albeit not an exact one. A lot of very smart people have a lot of opinions on the best way to optimize a website for search engines. Not all of the opinions are good, however. The best thing you can do is try to take in as much information as possible--but all with a grain of salt--and then form your own approach based on your own opinions and your experiences.

[SEOmoz](http://www.seomoz.org/) is a great place to start. Grab the [cheat sheet](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/the-web-developers-seo-cheat-sheet), read their articles (especially in the [Technical Issues category](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/category/22)) and use their tools.

[Google's Webmaster Central](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) is also invaluable, together with its and his [YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp). Make sure to follow [Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/)' blog and Twitter (though he's currently not tweeting) as well (he's they guy in most of the videos).

Other good sites include [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com), and its [SearchCap](http://searchengineland.com/searchcap)--a daily recap of lots of interesting search engine news. [Marketing Pilgrim](http://www.marketingpilgrim.com) is another good site, although it's more about search engine marketing in general and not specifically about SEO.

Then, experiment. Create sites (note: plural) where you can employ various techniques and see the results first-hand. You can even monetize your sites with AdSense or other means to get more than just knowledge out of it.

It's also worth noting that a lot of SEO are attributed to content. Search engines love blogs and press releases, as they provide dynamic content that they can index. Press releases are great because they normally generate backlinks when other sites pick them up (and edit, which prevents duplicate content for you!). Blog posts can do the same if they get noticed by other blogs.

After all, there's only so much you can do with code.

The most valuable tip I can give you, however, is to **stay away from blackhat SEO**. It may be tempting, but *it's not worth it*. It may be easy, but *it's not worth it*. If you get caught, you're finished. Play fair and the search engines will respond in kind.

Other than that; ask more specific questions. "How can I increase SEO" is very general and vague, and you're not going to get very good answers. "Do you think technique X is worthwhile?" or "Which is better, Y or Z?" are examples of questions that are easier to address.

Comment: For recent SEO information or tutorials check: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/seo-guidelines-and-checklists.html (I maintain these).

Answer (score 4):

From a developers point of view I would say always think SEO when building any site which will be seen and indexed by the search engines.

- Semantically Correct HTML
- `H1`. `H2`, `H3`, `P` tags are your friends, use them well
- Only 1 `H1` per page and not the company logo or name
- Rewrite your URLs so they don't use query strings
- Page title = `H1` (well the the `H1` keywords)
- Alt tags
- Label attributes for forms
- Watch your URL case. I don't care that IIS allows mixed case `mypage.aspx`, `MyPage.aspx,` and `MYPAGE.aspx` will all be seen by Google as different pages to fix this use the canonical URL meta tag.

The vast majority of SEO is done by the selection of keywords and writing the copy properly. As a developer you don't have to worry about this, your job is to give the copy its best chance of working possible.

Answer (score 2):

Very generic - use the [Microsoft SEO Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/web/seo/default.aspx) to see how a search engine sees your web page.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, be very careful if you outsource this service.  If you are interested in doing the SEO yourself, just stick to 'the basics'!

- Give images 'alt-text'
- Don't make exclusively flash-based sites.
- Fill out all tags and such completely
- Use heading appropriately
- Read, read and read some more.  There are articles available for every aspect of SEO.

Keep in mind people/companies do this as a full time job, so as a single developer, you can't focus too much on SEO.  Do things as you go, so you don't have to re-comb-over your complete stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Adhere to all the [web accessibility guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/) since essentially the search engine crawlers just like a blind user.

Answer (score 1):

if you want something you can take and run with straight away, i would suggest a basic ***on-page*** seo checklist like the following:

[image]

Source: [Bare Minimum On-Page SEO](http://pm4web.blogspot.com/2008/08/bare-minimum-on-page-seo.html)